# How to multiply list of matrices element-wise?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Consider the following code :

```
A=np.asmatrix([[1, 2],[3,4]])
B=[np.asmatrix([[2,0],[0,2]]), np.asmatrix([[10,0],[0,10]])]
```

I would like to do a matrix mutliplication which would return me :

`C=[A@B[0], A@B[1]]`

Is there a built-in method allowing to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a comprehension:

```
c = [A@E for E in B]
```

Comment: Is this kind of method speed efficient ? Because I know in python we must avoid to use loops (I am beginner in python)